# Sequence and series78

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a,b,c are positive real numbers and xabc/(a+b+c)<=(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2. Find the maximum value of x for which it always holds true.
I tried it by using A.M>=G.M but I am not able to get the answer please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to minimize $$ f(a,b,c) = \frac{\left((a+b)^2 + (a+b+4c)^2\right)(a+b+c)}{abc} $$ for $a,b,c>0$.
Note that $f$ is homogeneous of degree $0$, i.e. $f(ta,tb,tc) = f(a,b,c)$, so it is sufficient to minimize it on the surface $a+b+c=1$, $a,b,c > 0$.  Moreover, as $a, b$ or $c \to 0$ on this set, $f(a,b,c) \to \infty$, so a minimum does exist.  It will occur at
a point where $\nabla f$ is parallel to the normal to the surface, $(1,1,1)$.  Thus
we solve the equations 
$$ \eqalign{ \frac{\partial f}{\partial a} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\cr
             \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial c}\cr
             a+b+c &= 1\cr}$$
The solutions turn out to be $a=b=1,c=-1$ (not allowed because $c < 0$) and
$a=b=2/5$, $c= 1/5$, so the minimum value is $f(2/5, 2/5, 1/5) = 100$.